# z-index doesn't work in 2 absolute divs

Tags: css

I am trying replicate/to have a solution for my issue using the below URL.

http://www.cssmojo.com/extras/everything_you_always_wanted_to_know_about_z-index_but_were_afraid_to_ask/

Please look into the above URL and can anyone please tell me how to bring "A" on top of "a" keeping "A" as absolute position, I tried even in the above URL and not able to make "A" on top of "a" using z-index keeping "A" as absolute position.

Comment: Making `a` into `position: relative; z-index: -1;` whilst adding `position: absolute;` to `A` will bring `A` ontop of `a`. Is this what you wanted? or...?

Comment: @Edmund, that is not entirely accurate. "A" would still be below "a"; only the content inside "A" would be above "a".

Answer (score 0):

I think try to make "A" on top of "a" is impossible.

Because "A" is parent of "a".

If you want to make "A" on top of "a", Move "a" next "A".

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to render a child element behind its parent when the parent is positioned `absolute`.

That being said, giving the child element a negative `z-index` will place it behind all other content within the parent. The child will still be in front of the parent (so it will block a visible background/border), but depending on your use case that may be good enough.

Try setting the "A" `z-index` to `1` and the "a" `z-index` to `-1` on that site to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

- you should use A as `relative` and B as `absolute`
- then you can make A as top